# How do I open Internet Explorer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

I am running Windows 10 and need to be able to use Internet Explorer for some work, but I can't seem to locate it. I've already tried typing 'Internet Explorer' in Cortana search but it didn't work.

How can I open Internet Explorer on Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `iexplore`

[Happy browsings](http://www.wikihow.com/Switch-from-Internet-Explorer-to-Firefox)! :)

Comment: and if that doesn't work, you can always download internet explorer

Comment: @Blaine How exactly is that done?  Internet Explorer 11 cannot be downloaded on Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find Internet Explorer, open the [Turn Features On or Off dialog](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7247-windows-features-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) in `control panel`->`program & features` and make sure the Internet Explorer is selected:

[[image: screenshot of windows features dialog]

If the checkbox is missing, set it, click on OK, install IE and now you can find it via search or start IE with `iexplore.exe` in run dialog.

Answer (score 2):

You can also open the page in Microsoft  Edge, go to the menu at top right and select 'Open in Internet Explorer'